# In a slice category $\textbf{Set}/A$, what can be said about $\text{Hom}((A,id), (B,\theta_B))$?

Tags: category-theory

In a slice category $\textbf{Set}/A$, our objects are $(B,\theta_B)$ where $\theta_B:B \to A$, and morphisms $f:(B,\theta_B) \ to (C,\theta_C)$ must satisfy $\theta_B = \theta_C \circ f$.

One can show that $(A,id)$ is the terminal object in such category... I was then wondering about other properties regarding such slice category. For example, can we say something about $Hom((A,id),(B,\theta_B))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This category is **very** well understood, since it's once of the canonical examples of a [topos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos). In particular, there are lots and lots of things we can say about it, both abstractly, and via concrete computations.

For example, the slice category is [cartesian closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), and you can compute the internal hom explicitly. If we think of $\theta_B : B \to A$ as partitioning $B$ into disjoint fibres $B = \bigsqcup_{a \in A} \theta_B^{-1}(a)$, then $\underline{\text{Hom}}(\theta_B, \theta_C)$ is given by the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{a \in A} \text{Hom}_\mathsf{Set}(\theta_B^{-1}(a), \theta_C^{-1}(a))$ (with the obvious projection onto $A$).

You explicitly ask about interpretations of $\text{Hom}(\text{id}_A, \theta_B)$, and as has been mentioned this agrees with the [sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) of $\theta_B : B \to A$. There is also a geometric interpretation as the [global sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) of the "bundle" represented by $\theta_B$. This perspective may or may not be helpful, depending on your background.

As for places to read more about this, the properties of $\mathsf{Set} \big / A$ will be thoroughly covered in any good textbook on topos theory. You can find a lot of worked out examples for this category in particular in chapter 4 of Goldblatt's *Topoi: The Categorical Analysis of Logic*, but I actually don't recommend this book as a whole (even though, for you in particular, I do recommend that chapter!). Instead, if this is interesting, I would suggest reading (easier) Reyes, Reyes, and Zolfaghari's [*Generic Figures and Their Gluings*](https://marieetgonzalo.files.wordpress.com/2004/06/generic-figures.pdf) or (harder) Mac Lane and Moerdijk's [*Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*](http://atondwal.org/Sheaves_in_Geometry_and_Logic__MacLane_Moerdijk.pdf).

Since you mention you're particularly interested in applications to programming, I would also recommend Lambek and Scott's [*Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic*](https://github.com/Mzk-Levi/texts/blob/master/Lambek%20J.,%20Scott%20P.J.%20Introduction%20to%20Higher%20Order%20Categorical%20Logic.pdf), which explicitly covers the connection between topos theory and type theory.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This set, by definition, consists of maps $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ such that $\theta_B\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$. In other words, $f$ is a right-inverse to $\theta_B$. In particular, this set is empty unless $\theta_B$ is surjective.

More generally, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a category and $A$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$, then $(A,\mathrm{id}_A)$ is a terminal object in the slice category $\mathcal{C}/A$ and the set $\mathrm{Hom}((A,\mathrm{id}_A),(B,\theta_B))$ for an object $(B,\theta_B)$ in $\mathcal{C}/A$ consists of morphisms $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ such that $\theta_B\circ f=\mathrm{id}_A$. In this case, $f$ is called a *section* of $\theta_B$ and the existence of such a section is (by definition) equivalent to $\theta_B$ being a *split epimorphism*. Every split epimorphism is an epimorphism, but not every epimorphism is necessarily a split epimorphism in general categories (unlike in $\mathbf{Set}$, where epimorphisms and split epimorphisms are both the same thing as surjections).

Comment: any good references on the properties of slice categories?

Comment: That's very broad. What are you looking for?

Comment: Im trying to understand how slice categories fit within programming. More specifically, I want to understand how they relate to typeclasses... Hence, I'm trying to get a feel for the properties available.

Comment: @Thorgott Small correction: your $f$ will be a split _monomorphism_, not a split _epimorphism_.

Comment: @DaniëlApol It was supposed to be the other morphism, thanks for catching that.